# Name of virtualhost (apache)

Tags: apache, virtualhost, localhost

I need to create virtualhost with name "virtualhost_name". To access it with `http://virtualhost_name`

I have a pattern:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jan@novak.cz
    DocumentRoot "path"
    ServerName Name_of_server
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/log.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

***Where should I write the name?***

Comment: `ServerName`, obviously...

Answer (score 1):

There are two places that you can write (you can use both of them):

- ServerName: is the "internal" name of the vhost. It is not necessary the full qualified domain name. Just "myvhost" could be ok. Of course you can use the full name like "myvhost.example.com".
- ServerAlias: is other names. It is useful when you want multiple domain names for the same vhost.

For example: you have a website that you want to host both example.com and example.net:

```
ServerName example
ServerAlias example.com example.net www.example.com www.example.net
```

Comment: Fully Qualified Domain Name explained: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name

Comment: Thanks for the link. Of course, sort name or FQDN in ServerName and ServerAlias, there is no rule, however I always use as in the code above. One "principle" domain and many aliases.

Comment: I just wanted to clear up the terminology...

Comment: ServerName should not be an internal name, it should be the/a name as used by clients. It will be used for generating self-referential URLs.

Comment: If you are on windows you may want to add the virtual host name to your hosts file `system32/etc/hosts`